# How to create a new tag on the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tag-creation

I know how to create a new tag on the SE website, if I have enough reputation. But yesterday, I asked a question through Stack Exchange android app. I needed two tags for my question. One was available, so I just searched it & added. The other one I wanted to create (I have reputation to create new tags on site). But I could not do so on the android app.

How to create a new tag while on the Stack Exchange Android app? If this is currently not supported, then can this be added in the newer update?